# elasticsearch rails sort error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am getting error with elasticsearch sort.

references:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html

I am using elasticsearch-model with rails. The following snippet was not sorting and giving me error.

```
Ad.search(query: {
    sort: [{posted_on: {order: "asc"}},
      ],
    match: {
      description: {
        query: params[:search]
      }
    }
  })
```

The following is error when trying from terminal.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "description": {
        "query": "good center location"
      }
    },
    "sort": [
      "_score"
    ]
  }
}'
```

response is:

```
{
  "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[eF0LAz1gQxOXKPlYGjj9eA][.marvel-2014.06.07][0]: SearchParseException[[.marvel-2014.06.07][0]: query[block.2.description:good block.2.description:center block.2.description:location],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n   \"query\" : {\n     \"match\" : {\n       \"description\" : {\n         \"query\" : \"good center location\"\n       }\n     },\n     \"sort\" : [\"_score\"]\n   }]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_ARRAY \"sort\"]; }{[eF0LAz1gQxOXKPlYGjj9eA][.marvel-2014.05.29][0]: SearchParseException[[.marvel-2014.05.29][0]: query[block.2.description:good block.2.description:center block.2.description:location],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n   \"query\" : {\n     \"match\" : {\n       \"description\" : {\n         \"query\" : \"good center location\"\n       }\n     },\n     \"sort\" : [\"_score\"]\n   }]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_ARRAY \"sort\"]; }{[eF0LAz1gQxOXKPlYGjj9eA][.marvel-2014.05.31][0]: SearchParseException[[.marvel-2014.05.31][0]: query[block.2.description:good block.2.description:center block.2.description:location],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n   \"query\" : {\n     \"match\" : {\n       \"description\" : {\n         \"query\" : \"good center location\"\n       }\n     },\n     \"sort\" : [\"_score\"]\n   }]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_ARRAY \"sort\"]; }{[eF0LAz1gQxOXKPlYGjj9]}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most immediately without looking at it deeply, it looks like this is not valid json (checked here: http://jsonlint.com/)

What you posted would look like

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "description": {
                "query": "good center location"
            }
        },
        "sort": [
            "_score"
        ]
     }
```

Whereas

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "description": {
                "query": "good center location"
            }
        },
        "sort": [
            "_score"
        ]
    }
}
```

would be valid

Another issue is that sort is not a sub query of query. Looking at their usage example you can see that it is not nested [image] [(Source)](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_sort_mode_example_usage).

In addition score is the default sort so that parameter is not really necessary

> In Elasticsearch the relevance score is represented by the floating point number returned in the search results as the _score, so the default sort order is: _score descending.

[Source](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting.html#_sorting)

Something like [Marvel](http://www.elasticsearch.com/products/marvel/) (free during development) would help prevent these kind of errors as it checks the json being passed in 
 
[image: checks]
(red box signifies an error)